# How to capture the entire screen DC, like in windows Snipping Tool?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to make my own implementation of snipping tool in windows. Now i'm stuck with area choosing: i need to lock screen to allow user to choose area for saving. Like in original program, when it's activated, screen area behind snipping tool window becomes pale and inactive, and all drawing actions, like videos in browser, are interrupted.
In my earler implementation on Delphi, i used large window over screen area and moved screenshot on it, but it's certainly bad solution. What can you advise?

I'm using only winapi.
No qt or anything like this.

Comment: You seem to keep information to yourself. I cannot see anything bad about your implemented solution. Why is it *"certainly bad"*?

Comment: because snipping tool uses something nicer

Comment: *"Something nicer"* is not a very helpful specification. You won't receive much feedback, if you don't explain the problem you are trying to solve, in sufficient detail.

Comment: okay, then, lock screen activities by NOT using big window over screen.

Comment: The snipping tool does not deactivate or lock anything, the faded area is just an image of the desktop taken when a new snip is created.

Comment: i know
i'm trying to say that i need GetDC(NULL) alternative that doesn't allow other apps to override my drawings on the screen. for example, try to draw something using GetDC(NULL), and then hover your mouse above your drawing. it will be damaged in some places that were updated by window behind, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetDC()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from WinAPI, specifying `NULL` as first parameter:

> **Parameters**
>
> `hWnd [in]`
>
> A handle to the window whose `DC` is to be retrieved. If this value is
>   `NULL`, `GetDC` retrieves the `DC` for the entire screen.

Comment: and how do i lock screen activities after this?